# API data visualization in Google GEOChart

Tags: php, api, google-visualization

I'm adding data dynamically from my API to Google Geo chart, but there is an error: `"Error: Not an array"`
Can someone find the error in my code?

**MyApi.php**

```
function Mappa($sesso, $anno){
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    require('../php/config.php');
    #CONNESSIONE AL DATABASE
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "xxxx", "xxx");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) #SE C'È UN ERRORE DI CONNESSIONE, MI FERMO SUBITO
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $recordsTot=array();
    $recordsTot =  select($mysqli,"SELECT Country, Value AS data FROM disMondiale WHERE SUBJECT='$sesso' AND TIME='$anno'");
    foreach($results as $result)
    {
        $geo_chart_data[] = array($recordsTot['Country'], (int)$recordsTot['data']);
    }
    return json_encode($geo_chart_data);
}
```

**getByTotMappa.php**

```
require('MyAPI.php');
if(! isset($_REQUEST['anno'])) exit();
$anno = $_REQUEST['anno'];
echo Mappa("LRHUTTTT", $anno);
```

**JS code**

```
function Mappa(node, anno){
    var annoC=anno;
    $.getJSON("./api/getByTotMappa.php?anno="+annoC+"&src=", function(data)            
    {
        creaMappa(data, node)
    });
}

function creaMappa(data,node){
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap(data,node));
}

function drawRegionsMap(series, node) {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({series});
    var options = {colorAxis: {colors: ['#FFFFFF', '#048ABF', '#025172', '#023E5A', '#013453']}};
    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('#'+node));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

**Initialization**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['geochart']});
    var node = "container";
    Mappa(node,2011);
});
```

What am I doing wrong?